# how to avoid the "Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory" during API import requests

Tags: node.js, promise, stack-overflow

I've got a nodejs script that read data in excels files and send it to a nodejs API with 'request'. this script works fine with a small amount of data. But when i test with an Excel with 60.000 lines, it breaks with error:
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

```
function fillWithFile(file, path, header, fileConfig) { 
    let workbook = XLSX.readFile(path + '/' + file); // read file
    for (var sheetIterator = 0; sheetIterator < workbook.SheetNames.length; sheetIterator++) { // for each tab in excel file
        let worksheetJson = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[sheetIterator]]); // transforme one tab of excel to JSON
        let config = fileConfig[workbook.SheetNames[sheetIterator]]; // get the config for the current tab

        let datasPromises = getPromises(worksheetJson, config, header);

        Promise.all(datasPromises).then(function (data) {
            var dataString = '{"data":' + JSON.stringify(data) + ',"options":{"purgeBefore":false}}';
            let options = {
                url: API_URL + '/' + config.service + 's/import',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: header,
                body: dataString
            }
            request.post(options, function (err, res, body) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('Server responded with:', body);
            });
        });
    }
}

function getPromises(worksheetJson, config, header) {
        let datasPromises = [];
        let promises = [];
        for (let lineIterator = 0; lineIterator < worksheetJson.length; lineIterator++) { // for each line
            datasPromises.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                for (let key in config.columns) { // for each column in config
                    if (config.columns[key].service !== undefined) { // if service exist we need to get id of the object in this service.
                        promises.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                            findChildren(worksheetJson[lineIterator], config.columns[key], header)
                                .then(function (res) {
                                    resolve({ key: key, data: res.id });
                                });
                        }));
                    }
                    else {
                        promises.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                            resolve({ key: key, data: worksheetJson[lineIterator][config.columns[key]] });
                        }));
                    }
                }
                let tmpObj = {};
                Promise.all(promises).then(function (values) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                        tmpObj[values[i].key] = values[i].data;
                    }
                    resolve(tmpObj);
                });
            }));
        }
        return datasPromises;
}

function findChildren(sheetData, config, header) { // get children with get request
    let dataObj = {};
    let searchParams;
    for (let key in config.columns) {
        dataObj[key] = sheetData[config.columns[key]];
        if (searchParams === undefined) searchParams = key + '=' + sheetData[config.columns[key]];
        else searchParams += '&' + key + '=' + sheetData[config.columns[key]];
    }

    var headers = {
        'Authorization': header.Authorization,
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    };
    var options = {
        url: API_URL + '/' + config.service + 's?' + searchParams,
        headers: headers
    };

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                try {
                        resolve(JSON.parse(body));
                } catch (e) {
                    reject(e);
                }
            }
            else {
                return reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The script use a huge amount of memory and he ends up to crash ...
Anyone have an idea how i can solve this ?
I think, i have to find a way to force promises to resolve instantly for avoid the memory overflow.
thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you use async/await?

Comment: I've try to use it, but surely not the right way ... I have not seen any difference ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you don't control parallelism and when everything runs 'at once' - it causes memory issues.

I've tried to rewrite the code using async/await - effectively all operations are now serial:

```
async function fillWithFile(file, path, header, fileConfig) {
  let workbook = XLSX.readFile(path + '/' + file); // read file
  for (var sheetIterator = 0; sheetIterator < workbook.SheetNames.length; sheetIterator++) { // for each tab in excel file
    const worksheetJson = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[sheetIterator]]); // transforme one tab of excel to JSON
    const config = fileConfig[workbook.SheetNames[sheetIterator]]; // get the config for the current tab

    const data = await getData(worksheetJson, config, header);

    const dataString = '{"data":' + JSON.stringify(data) + ',"options":{"purgeBefore":false}}';
    const options = {
      url: API_URL + '/' + config.service + 's/import',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: header,
      body: dataString
    };

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request.post(options, function (err, res, body) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log('Server responded with:', body);
        resolve(body);
      })
    });
  }
}

async function getData(worksheetJson, config, header) {
  const data = [];
  for (let lineIterator = 0; lineIterator < worksheetJson.length; lineIterator++) { // for each line
    const values = {};
    for (let key in config.columns) { // for each column in config
      if (config.columns[key].service !== undefined) { // if service exist we need to get id of the object in this service.
        const res = await findChildren(worksheetJson[lineIterator], config.columns[key], header);
        values[key] = res.id;
      }
      else {
        values[key] = worksheetJson[lineIterator][config.columns[key]];
      }
    }
    data.push(values);    
  }
  return data;
}

function findChildren(sheetData, config, header) { // get children with get request
  let dataObj = {};
  let searchParams;
  for (let key in config.columns) {
    dataObj[key] = sheetData[config.columns[key]];
    if (searchParams === undefined) searchParams = key + '=' + sheetData[config.columns[key]];
    else searchParams += '&' + key + '=' + sheetData[config.columns[key]];
  }

  var headers = {
    'Authorization': header.Authorization,
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  };
  var options = {
    url: API_URL + '/' + config.service + 's?' + searchParams,
    headers: headers
  };

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        try {
          resolve(JSON.parse(body));
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      }
      else {
        return reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

You now run import like this:

```
fillWithFile(..args).then(() => console.log('done'))
```

Comment: Nice, it's look's great. I've tested it but I have the following problem:
ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined.
I know it's an error with async/await but i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Are you using Babel? Try requiring `require("babel-polyfill")` in your project...

Comment: I haven't use Babel for node.js development, try to somehow disable generation of code for generators... node has native support in the latest LTS versions, so it shouldn't be needed